# Reading from .csv-file into double-array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, csv

I have a question concerning LINQ queries and return types. I just want to read values from a .csv file, where there are double values separated by semicolon like this:

0,016;0,010;-0,020;-0,014;0,020;0,016;-0,019;-0,014;0,023;

The reading from the file works fine with the following statement:

```
        double pdValue;
        double[] pdValues;

        var values = File.ReadAllLines(path)
            .Select(a => a.Split(';')
            .Select(str => double.TryParse(str, out pdValue) ? pdValue : 0));

        pdValues = values.ToArray();
```

But the last line returns the 'Cannot implicitly convert System.Collections.Generic.IENumerable< double> to double[]' error. Trying to get it to work with array changes the error to 'Cannot implicitly convert System.Collections.Generic.IENumerable< double>[] to double[]'.

When debugging, I can already see that the values variable holds all values from the file (somehow) as array...

I could not find anything yet, what could give me a hint on what exactly I am doing wrong here. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok you said the values variable  holds all values from the file (somehow) as array.. err cos you said a.Split(';') .. so now its an array of strings...

Comment: It's more usefull to use the `File.ReadLines` instead of the `File.ReadAllLines`, because the `File.ReadLines` streams the data instead of loading it full into the memory.

Comment: The file contains more than one line? So It would be a `double[][]` What do you need as result? `double[][]` or `double[]` _(all lines merged)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `values` variable type which is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>`. You should use this code:

```
 var values = File.ReadAllLines(path)
            .SelectMany(a => a.Split(';')
            .Select(str => double.TryParse(str, out pdValue) ? pdValue : 0));

pdValues = values.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the .SelectMany statement fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

The `ReadAllLine` method will return an array of strings ( Lets say Array A). The `Split` method that you have used is going to give you a string array split by ";" for every item of Array A. So the end result would be an array of array. That is the reason for the error.

You can try :

```
var values = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToString()
            .Split(';').Select(str => double.TryParse(str, out pdValue) ? pdValue : 0);
```